# Jquery plugin filthypillow. How to format time to 24 hour clock

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery plugin filthypillow(http://aef-.github.io/jquery.filthypillow/) to display a datetime picker. By default it seems that time is shown in AM/PM e.g when I set default time as 00:00 it is shown as 12:00 AM.

I want to format the time in 24hour clock but looking through documentation I can't find how to do this.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the filthypillow object, you can use the `enable24HourTime` option like so:

```
var $fp = $(selector_of_fp_target);
$fp.filthypillow({
  enable24HourTime: true
});
```

I found this answer on the [FilthyPillow GitHub](https://github.com/aef-/jquery.filthypillow/blob/master/jquery.filthypillow.js). At version 1.5.0, you can find the `defaults` object at `line 16`. And you'll see `enable24HourTime` there, with a default of `false`.